# Compilation error while passing two variadic parameter in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I need to queue task as function pointers. The argument for function pointer is a list of parameters and a callback.

I created a class which stores theses tasks. Now I need to write a template method which takes a function pointer, parameters and callback.

I tried creating below class, but is not compiling...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class TaskScheduler {
public:
    TaskScheduler() = default;
    virtual ~TaskScheduler() {}

    template <typename... TParam>
    struct Callback {
        using Type = std::function<void(TParam...)>;
    };

    template<typename TCallback, typename... TRequestParam>
    void queue(void (*requestFunction)(TRequestParam..., typename TCallback::Type),
                TRequestParam... args, typename TCallback::Type callback) {
        doQueue([this, requestFunction, args..., callback](){
            requestFunction(args..., callback);
        });
    }

    void fire() {
        for (auto task: mTasks) {
            task();
        }
    }

protected:
    void doQueue(std::function<void()> task) {
        mTasks.push_back(task);
    }

    std::vector<std::function<void()>> mTasks;
};

class Test1 {};

class Test2 {};

class Test3 {};

void function1(Test1 *a1, std::shared_ptr<Test2> a2, std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Test2>)> a3) {
}

int main(int, char **) {
    TaskScheduler ns;    

    Test1 *test1Ptr = 0;
    auto test2Sptr = std::make_shared<Test2>();

    std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Test2>)> callback = [](std::shared_ptr<Test2>){};

    ns.queue<TaskScheduler::Callback<std::shared_ptr<Test2>>, Test1 *, std::shared_ptr<Test2>>(&function1, test1Ptr, test2Sptr, callback);

    ns.fire();
}
```

With clang I get the error,

```
mtest.cc:55:8: error: no matching member function for call to 'queue'
    ns.queue<TaskScheduler::Callback<std::shared_ptr<Test2>>, Test1 *, std::shared_ptr<Test2>>(&function1, test1Ptr, test2Sptr, callback);
    ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mtest.cc:17:10: note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction
    void queue(void (*requestFunction)(TRequestParam..., typename TCallback::Type),
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04c5e89d54d12e22). What error message did you get?

Comment: @nwp use clang.

Comment: I can't find the issue and given it compiles with gcc, this may be a clang bug. That said, this solution seems to be very needlessly complex, `queue` should probably just take a `std;:function<void()>` and enqueue it. Specifying template parameters of functions that relate to the inputs is rarely idiomatic C++ (usually, when you specify a template parameter explicitly, it relates to the output), and tends to make things more error prone. So I would suggest re-engineering this regardless (though someone should figure out if it's a clang bug, and if so, submit it).

Comment: [Clang indeed shows an error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a94636d25e48b4c): *no matching member function for call to 'queue': `ns.queue<TaskScheduler::Callback<std::shared_ptr<Test2>>, Test1 *, std::shared_ptr<Test2>>(&function1, test1Ptr, test2Sptr, callback);`*.

Comment: @nir-friedman I have an existing code base where if the above declared queue function works then I have little refactoring to do.